# Import Tab Separated File Into sqlite - OperationalError Near ")"

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to import a tab separated file ('pageviews') into sqlite ('empty_db.sqite') but continue to get the error message 'OperationalError: near ")": syntax error'.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import csv

con = sqlite3.connect('empty_db.sqlite')
con.execute('CREATE TABLE tbl(Field1 TEXT, Field2 TEXT, Field3 INTEGER, Field4 INTEGER);')

csvfile = open('pageviews', 'r', encoding = 'utf8')
csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
header = next(csvReader)
for rec in csvReader:
    con.execute("INSERT INTO tbl VALUES %s" %str(tuple(rec)))
csvfile.close()
con.commit()
con.close()
```

This is the first five rows of my TSV file:

```
aa Main_Page 1 0
aa.d Main_Page 1 0
aa.m Main_Page 1 0
ab 1942 1 0
ab 1990 1 0
```

Any help would be much appreciated - thank you!

Comment: can you post the stacktrace? and if the error comes from the execute in the loop, can you print `tuple(rec)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged your question with a `pandas` tag, but you don't use it...

If you want to use pandas it might look much easier:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

In [288]: con = sqlite3.connect('d:/temp/empty_db.sqlite')

In [289]: fn = r'D:\temp\.data\123.csv'

In [290]: df = pd.read_csv(fn, delim_whitespace=True, header=None).add_prefix('col')

In [291]: df
Out[291]:
   col0       col1  col2  col3
0    aa  Main_Page     1     0
1  aa.d  Main_Page     1     0
2  aa.m  Main_Page     1     0
3    ab       1942     1     0
4    ab       1990     1     0

In [292]: df.to_sql('tbl', con, index=False)
```

SQLite:

```
D:\temp>sqlite3 empty_db.sqlite
SQLite version 3.10.1 2016-01-13 21:41:56
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .header on
sqlite> .mode columns
sqlite> select * from tbl;
col0        col1        col2        col3
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
aa          Main_Page   1           0
aa.d        Main_Page   1           0
aa.m        Main_Page   1           0
ab          1942        1           0
ab          1990        1           0
```

Reading back from SQLite:

```
In [293]: x = pd.read_sql('select * from tbl', con)

In [294]: x
Out[294]:
   col0       col1  col2  col3
0    aa  Main_Page     1     0
1  aa.d  Main_Page     1     0
2  aa.m  Main_Page     1     0
3    ab       1942     1     0
4    ab       1990     1     0
```

Comment: Thanks - my intention was to import the data into 'empty_db.sqlite' and then convert it to a DataFrame, but I was having a hard time even getting it into the sqlite DB.  So from here I could use this line to convert it to a DataFrame?  df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl", con)

Comment: So the code put it in a DataFrame, but all four of the columns from the TSV file in the second column of the DataFrame, with the row numbers listed in the first column.

Comment: @6114617, please post a sample input data set (ideally 3-5 first rows from your TSV file) into your question

Comment: @6114617, i've updated the answer with a real example - please check

Comment: Great - this worked perfectly.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @6114617, glad i could help :)